# Как правильнее реализовать операций над мультимножествами?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Даны два неубывающих массива чисел. Нужно сформировать неубывающий массивы, являющийся объединением мультимножеств.

Пока придумал как это сделать за `length1 + length2` шагов таким способом:

```
public static int[] MultisetUnion(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int pA = 0;
    int pB = 0;
    var result = new List<int>();

    while (pA < a.Length || pB < b.Length)
    {
        // Не осталось элементов в A - выталкиваем оставшиеся из B
        if (pA == a.Length)
            result.Add(b[pB++]);
        // Аналогично по достижения конца B
        else if (pB == b.Length)
            result.Add(a[pA++]);
        // Добавляем в результирующий массив сначала меньшее число, чтобы сохранить свойство неубывания
        else if (a[pA] == b[pB])
        {
            result.Add(a[pA]);
            ++pA;
            ++pB;
        }
        else if (a[pA] < b[pB])
            result.Add(a[pA++]);
        else
            result.Add(b[pB++]);
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Возможно ли решить эту задачу с помощью LINQ, без этого громоздкого цикла? Или может другим способом, более быстрым или грамотным.

Comment: Можно через Linq - объединить и сортировать, но вы ведь не этого хотите?

Comment: Сортировка это квадратичная асимптотика. Поэтому не подойдет. Интересует возможность записи алгоритма с такой же асимптотикой, но аккуратнее, либо более производительного (но ниже O(n+m) уже не может быть в этом случае, верно?)

Comment: Оставляйте свой алгоритм и не забивайте голову. Ну, как вариант, я бы переписал метод в виде генератора, возможно, но алгоритм при этом все равно останется тем же самым. Ваш метод можно улучшить только тем, что сразу заводить массив нужного размера, а не добавлять элементы в List - это приводит к лишним копированиям внутреннего массива при его расширении

Comment: У сортировки асимптотика n log n, вообще-то.

Comment: Ну у вас нормальный алгоритм, только не понятно зачем вы сравниваете a[pA] == b[pB] вам нужно удалять дубликаты?

Comment: B. Vandyshev, Объединением мультимножеств называется мультимножество, состоящее из всех элементов, которые присутствуют хотя бы в одном из мультимножеств, и кратность каждого элемента равна максимальной кратности соответствующих элементов в объединяемых мультимножествах.

Comment: VladD, только перехожу с Си, думал тут тоже qsort с O(n^2)

Comment: @BanyRule: Насколько мне помнится, qsort имеет среднюю асимптотику O(n log n), квадрат там только в наихудшем случае.

Comment: @VladD Все верно. Имелся в виду наихудший случай

Answer (score 2):

С вашей структурой данных (массив с повторениями) не очень удобно работать.

Если поменять носитель на `Dictionary<T, int>` (который отображает значение в его кратность), то Union можно организовать так:

```
Dictionary<T, int> Union<T>(Dictionary<T, int> s1, Dictionary<T, int> s2) =>
    s1.Keys.Union(s2.Keys)
           .ToDictionary(k => k,
                         k => { s1.TryGetValue(k, out var v1);
                                s2.TryGetValue(k, out var v2);
                                return Math.Max(v1, v2); });
```

Я воспользовался тем, что `TryGetValue` при отсутствии ключа возвращает `default(int)`, то есть 0.

Если дополнительно определить для вспомогательную функцию

```
public static int GetArity<T>(this Dictionary<T, int> self, T key)
{
    self.TryGetValue(key, out var arity);
    return arity;
}
```

(которая возвращает количество вхождений элемента в мультимножество), то код становится изящнее:

```
Dictionary<T, int> Union<T>(Dictionary<T, int> s1, Dictionary<T, int> s2) =>
    s1.Keys.Union(s2.Keys).ToDictionary(k => k, k => Math.Max(s1.GetArity(k), s2.GetArity(k)));
```

Плюсы новой структуры данных: поиск, добавление и удаление за (амортизированные) О(1). Объединение/пересечение за O(суммы количеств элементов). Минусы — нет сортировки.

Comment: Ну Union же просто объединяет множества, а автору требуется на выходе упорядоченная последовательность... Например `{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7} + { 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6 } = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7 }`. У вас же ключи вернутся в порядке, например таком: `1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6` Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: @Андрей: В словаре порядок ключей по идее неважен. Моё предложение как раз и состоит в том, чтобы использовать не упорядоченный массив с повторениями, а словарь. Будет работать так: https://ideone.com/IXZNqX

Comment: Мне-то понятно, главное чтобы автор понял, а то он будет ждать на выходе сортированную последовательность, а она здесь не гарантируется.

Comment: @Андрей: Обнаружил, что нужна не сумма, а максимум.

Comment: Максимум? Почему?

Comment: @Андрей: Ну вроде так определяется операция. Вот например: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MultiSet%2Funion

Comment: Ну если уж у нас "канонические" множества, то там вообще повторяющихся элементов быть не должно. Просто автор своей терминологией вас в заблуждение ввёл, у него вовсе никакие не множества, а просто слияние двух сортированных массивов

Comment: @Андрей: Не, это ж канонические мультимножества. Есть такая штука.

Comment: @Андрей: Вот тут тоже посмотрите на объединение: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Example_multiset_operations

Comment: Ок, я пас тогда %)

Comment: Со словарями однозначно красивее. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @BanyRule: Пожалуйста! Рад, если помогло.